# How can I only print today's reservations from the MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwXi6.png)

i am newbie coder. my study project is timetable.

i want to print out a list of reservation for example 2021-04-06.

but Not only the 2021-04-06.

all the reservation dates were printed.

all failed...

i use NodeJS, express, mongoDB, mongoose.

help me.

```
User Schema({
    name: user1
    clients: [
        client1,
        client2
    ]
});
```

```
Client Schema({
    name: client1
    phone: 00000000,
    gender: 1,
    reservation:[
        {
            date: 2021-04-06T00:00:00.000Z,
            time: "14:00"
            cancel: "off",
            noshow: "on",
        },
        {
            date: 2021-04-10T00:00:00.000Z,
            time: "14:00"
            cancel: "off",
            noshow: "off",
        }
    ],
    memo: String,
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
},
{
    name: client2
    phone: 00000002,
    gender: 0,
    reservation:[
        {
            date: 2021-04-06T00:00:00.000Z,
            time: "10:00"
            note: "first"
            cancel: "off",
            noshow: "on",
        },
        {
            date: 2021-04-12T00:00:00.000Z,
            time: "14:00"
            note: "second"
            createdAt: Date,
            cancel: "off",
            noshow: "off",
        }
    ],
    memo: String,
    user: user1
})
```

Comment: Your schema doesn't match the query in you screenshot.  Is it `reservation.date` or `reserve.date` ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, provide code as formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Whenever one has to work with date and times then I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. It makes your life easier.

Comment: Why do you store data and time values in separate fields? Better use just one field, `Date` object has date and time components.

Comment: thanks you. It is shown differently in the photo, but it is actually unified as a reserve. I made the html tag input easier, I separated the time and date. it's better to combine them, so I'll do them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/m39zdyqq8id

Use aggregation query

Use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to break into individual documents and use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter by date.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$reservation" },
  { $match: { "reservation.date": ISODate("2021-04-06") } }
])
```

Comment: thank you. I found my way this way. In CLI, this method works perfectly. But in mongoose or javascript it shouldn't be this way. {$ match: {"reserve.noshow": "on"}} This works fine. There seems to be a problem with the date search method. I tried a few things but it failed. ```{$ match: {"reserve.noshow": {$ date: '2021-04-06'}}};``` // ```const a = '2021-04-06'; const b = a.toISOString(); {$ match: {"reserve.noshow": b}};```  //  ```const c = new date ('2021-04-06'); {$ match: {"reserve.noshow": c}};``` All has failed.. Is there any way?

Comment: i ``` { $unwind: "$reserve" },  { $match: { "reserve.date": new Date("2021-04-05T00:00:00.000Z") } ```  I was successful.
In Mongoose, you have to set a new date ("2021-04-05"). Thank you very much!